# How to deploy a custom list with custom Schema and have it synchronize across variations?

Tags: custom-list, variations

I'm digging through `SharePoint.Server.Publishing.Variations`, but can't find anything useful.

When I create a custom list (`BaseTemplate=100`) in a variation site. I get the new ribbon tab "Variations":

[image]

However when I deploy a custom list (e.g. ID `10000`) the variations tab is not existing. I also cannot add the list to the variation hierarchy so it is automatically synched across variations.

**How do I synch a custom list across variations? Can I work with content types (site collection based)?**

My goal is to create a news display webpart with a news list backend. The list shall be automatically synched across variations and each variation hence has the news in their own language. I fail at creating the synched list, the webpart with different settings per language is no problem.

---

**EDIT:** It seems that synchronization is only possible with custom lists as described here: [Variations Tab missing from List](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0729a982-f044-4ca7-9f3f-cc18a4a8f21a/variations-tab-missing-from-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment). What is the best practice then? Add everything else via feature receiver to that list (e.g. attach content type, different views)? I guess I can't use a custom schema then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a custom list definition with a new id you loose some out of the box functionality that are coupled to a base template.

Best to create a [list instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx) with a [custom schema](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.nl/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-listinstance.html). This way you can deploy youre customized list and keep all the functionality.

Second way is to create youre definition with the same type. But thats not recommanded.

Comment: Woah! You can add a list instance with a custom schema? How cool is that?! As my lists don't need to be recreatable (i.e. a user can create a new list of type "My special list") - this could really work. Same type I would never do, basically breaking the default type.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade list instances with custom schemas? I first create the list with `CustomSchema` set to something useful. How would I upgrade said schema? Just replacing the `schema.xml`?

Comment: Oh.. and it seems like `CustomSchema` breaks multilanguage: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sharepoint2010/sharepoint2010programming.aspx?ID=a64d47f6-a04f-4192-bec0-b823453d7512

Comment: When you create a site in a english the list is in english. When you create youre site in dutch it is dutch however if you change your browser language it does not change

Comment: Sure the URL stays the same, but you can use resource files to localize pretty much everything: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955226%28v=office.14%29.aspx and that function seems to be affected.

Comment: True.. but in variation you create sites in english and for example dutch.. then the your list in that sites are in english and dutch .. Other option is ofcourse the list defination with the same type

Comment: Hmhmm... Will really have to play with this. If I have a "News" list with the "important" column. It should be "belangrijk" in Dutch, otherwise the users wouldn't know what to do - though all they should do is translate anyways.